# Can't I select into list of primitive type in EF?

Tags: c#, select, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nullreferenceexception

I want to understand why my code throws a null reference exception.

`DisruptionReportSteps` are not null, the problem is not in them. My guess is that by throwing nre, EF tells that it can't project my bools into a list, because it is not possible to deal with collections of primitive types. Am I right?

```
 var disruptionReportsQuery = _dbContext.Reports
    // query
            .Select(report => new
            {
                AreStepsFilled = new List<bool>
                {
                    report.DisruptionReportFirstStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportSecondStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportThirdStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportFourthStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportFifthStep.IsFilled,
                },
            })
```

If I do:

```
var disruptionReportsQuery = _dbContext.Reports
    // query
            .Select(report => new
            {
                 IsFirstStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFirstStep.IsFilled,
                 IsSecondStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportSecondStep.IsFilled,
                 IsThirdStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportThirdStep.IsFilled,
                 IsFourthStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFourthStep.IsFilled,
                 IsFifthStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFifthStep.IsFilled,
            })
```

it works.

Still, I want to make sure that I understand why such behavior appears.

Comment: What version ef are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework Core 3.1.4

Comment: I did exactly the same thing with various EF core versions (3 and 5) and I can execute a query similar to your first one without any problems. If a query expression throws an NRE it usually indicates a bug in the translation logic, because none of the values are actually evaluated in C# code. It would help to know more details, like a stack trace and the database provider (query provider) to get to the bottom of this. The work-around in the answer doesn't contribute to understanding.

Comment: @GertArnold I am sorry but it is 3.1 EF. It doesn't have much problem with translations. It takes all records from DB without any warnings and convert them after this. It it would be EF 5 , it would give a translation error since it works differently and trys to convert query to SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold, I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.4. I took Sergey's explanation for granted..

Comment: Would be interesting for them to see the stack trace of the NRE (if they're watching). With SQL server it's not a problem. OTOH I can imagine it won't gain high priority to support this kind of less common output shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because you trying to init the list with values from query, not from the concrete list of values. But values of the query are always null, they will be assigned when query runs (by calling ToList() or ToArray() for example).

So if you want to create a list of primitives, you have to create a list of objects at first. After this you can init the list.

```
var disruptionReports = _dbContext.Reports

            .Select(report => new
            {
                 IsFirstStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFirstStep.IsFilled,
                 IsSecondStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportSecondStep.IsFilled,
                 IsThirdStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportThirdStep.IsFilled,
                 IsFourthStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFourthStep.IsFilled,
                 IsFifthStepFilled = report.DisruptionReportFifthStep.IsFilled,
            }).ToList();

 var disruptionReportsList = disruptionReports
            .Select(report => new
            {
                AreStepsFilled = new List<bool>
                {
                    report.DisruptionReportFirstStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportSecondStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportThirdStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportFourthStep.IsFilled,
                    report.DisruptionReportFifthStep.IsFilled,
                },
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This questions is not about achieving a result. It's about understanding what's going on.

Comment: I don't like to guess what is going on. I would like to know if it works or not. This will help to understand.

Comment: Well, I assume it works if you post it. I know that many people post "try this" answers, but shouldn't an answerer first try themselves? That said, if it works, it conceals the issue and doesn't contribute to understanding. "Good Is The Enemy Of Great".

Comment: Oh, I see now. Spasibo, Serezha.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is still just a work-around and the explanation doesn't hold water. See my comment on the question. Clearly, the query provider has trouble translating the expression into SQL when the array is wrapped into an anonymous type. Either building the list directly, or wrapping in an anonymous type, it's only about expression translation, not about values being `null`.

Comment: @GertArnold. I am sorry but I am not a professor , I am a professional programmer with 40+ yeas experience. I usually don' t have any time and wish to research why because technology changes every day and new version will be faster then I finish my research.  My task is to make the reliable working code as soon as possible. And sometimes I  have to  use my 6th sense for this.